# Send WooCommerce email notifications to billing and user email address

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications

I wanted to use `woocommerce_mail_headers` filter to send custom emails to billing email address and user email address.

I read a lot of different posts about this issue on the last days but i was not able to find a working solution.

The following code is ok when `$cc_email` and `$user_name` are predefined but not when they are variable (depending on `$order`).

`my_custom_email` is the id of my email template (very close to WooCommerce email ones)

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'cc_user_function', 10, 3);
 
function cc_user_function($headers, $email_id, $order) {
       
    if ($email_id == 'my_custom_email'){
         $order_nr = wc_get_order( $order );
         $user_id   = $order_nr->get_user_id();
        $cc_email = get_userdata($user_id)->user_email ;
      
           $user_name  = $user->get_first_name().' ';
           $user_name .= $user->get_last_name();

    $formatted_email = utf8_decode($user_name . ' <' . $cc_email . '>');

    $headers .= 'Cc: '.$formatted_email .'\r\n';
}

            return $headers;
}
```

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an instance of the WP_User object you can use `$order->get_user()`

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_email_headers( $header, $email_id, $order ) {
    // For a given email id & user id exists (no guests)
    if ( $email_id == 'customer_on_hold_order' && $order->get_user_id() > 0 ) {
        // Get an instance of the WP_User object
        $user = $order->get_user();
        
        // Get user email
        $user_email = $user->user_email;
        
        // Get first & last name
        $user_name = $user->first_name . ' ';
        $user_name .= $user->last_name;
    
        // Prepare the the data
        $formatted_email = utf8_decode( $user_name . ' <' . $user_email . '>' );

        // Add Cc to headers
        $header .= 'Cc: ' . $formatted_email . '\r\n';
    }

    return $header;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'filter_woocommerce_email_headers', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I copied the code in my functions.php but unfortunately it does not work. None email are sent.

Comment: @user16877254 
I have changed the email id to an existing email id, as your question contains little to no details about your custom email. Also know Cc is used for additional recipients, so if the billing and user email address are the same.. Code has been tested 2x and works

Comment: Thank you 7uc1f3r, I am sorry for this late answer but I had internet problems. Yes you are perfectly right, the code works for woocommerce processing-order email and yes billing and user email are different. My custom email is very close to on-hold order template email. I will double check my custom mail and get back to you. Thank you so much for your help.